# How to associate Scene Builder made components with Java class members?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Suppose I have designed some complex design in Scene Builder:

[image]

Now how to associate drawn TextField's with some Java class fields?

Not that for complex designs it is impossible (hard) to look for appropriate FXML code by eye and set `fx:id` there. Also, there is no way to set id's in SceneBuilder.

Is there any normal way to perform the task?

Comment: *"Also, there is no way to set id's in SceneBuilder."* This claim is false. You can set `fx:id` as well as `id` in SceneBuilder!

Comment: You are really right. It was IntelliJ who ate features!